# Problems compiling node.js version with Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, nfc, node-modules

I'm trying to run a electron Project with 10.16.0 node js version but an error ocurred.
I'm using this library https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc

I have tried to take another Electron version that works correctly with 10.16.0 node.js but did not work.

```
    "@pokusew/pcsclite": "^0.5.2",
    "electron-version": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "ava": "^2.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "electron": "^5.0.4",
    "mock-require": "^3.0.3",
    "triple-beam": "^1.3.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v6hO.png "error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the [electron-rebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild) package which  rebuilds native Node.js modules against the version of Node.js that your Electron project is using. This allows you to use native Node.js modules in Electron apps without your system version of Node.js matching exactly.

You can install this package using the below command,

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Then, whenever you install a new npm package, rerun electron-rebuild:

```
$(npm bin)/electron-rebuild
```

Or if you're on Windows:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

You can even create an alias as "rebuild" in your "scripts" section which you can use it whenever it is needed like this.

```
"scripts": {
  "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w yourmodule"
}
```

Once you add the above, you can use the below command,

```
npm run rebuild
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i'm getting this error when i do .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd

```An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Los proyectos de esta soluci n se van a compilar de uno en uno. Para habilitar la compilaci n en paralelo, agregue el modificador "/m".
addon.cpp
pcsclite.cpp
cardreader.cpp
win_delay_load_hook.cc
c:\users\terro\.electron-gyp\5.0.4\include\node\v8.h(4458): warning C4996: 'v8::WasmModuleObject::SerializedModule': se declar  desusado (compilando archivo de origen ..\src\addon.cpp) [C:path\nfc\nfc-pcsc\node_modules\@pokusew\pcsclite\build\pcsclite.vcxproj]```

Comment: If isn't clear what i am trying to say, this is the principal error ```× Rebuild Failed An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild```

Comment: Can you try entering this command in your command prompt? => `set env GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015` and re-run the `electron-rebuild` ?

Comment: Now i got another problem ```An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok```

Comment: Okay. Can you please try these commands one by one => `npm uninstall --save electron` and once it is done.. issue this command => `npm install --save electron@latest` and then try running the `electron-build` and see if it works.